# PostgreSQL 13 capture audit logs of actual IP address

Tags: postgresql, pgaudit

I am working on configuring PgAudit on my PostgreSQL database so when my clients access my PostgreSQL, it will capture a log of the action they perform.

My Client PC have got their actual IP address and a VPN connection address, the VPN connects to my PostgreSQL database server. The problem is how can I capture the actual IP address in my pgaudit log?

In my `postgresql.conf`, the below is my `configuration` :

```
log_line_prefix= '%t %a %u-%d-%h'
```

`%h` and `%r` captures the VPN IP address, is there anyway I can capture the actual IP address, or even all of the client IP address?

Comment: No. They are connecting through the VPN, so as far as Postgres is concerned, that is their "actual IP address".

Comment: The server doesn't even have that information, so it cannot log it